# Codeigniter Link to Accordion Item with Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, accordion, codeigniter-3

Using Codeigniter 3 and Bootstrap 4.

Background, I have a section of my website displaying 'Random Records', clicking on these should take you to the corresponding record. However it only works for my first page of records.

I have setup pagination in CI and it all works as expected, I can navigate through my pages and view 50 results on each page.

The 50 results on each page are displayed in a (click to expand) accordion list. The `href` of the accordion has the following format;

On page 1;

- Item 1 `results/#item1`
- Item 2 `results/#item2`
- Item 3 `results/#item3`
- etc.

On page 2;

- Item 51 `results/50#item51`
- Item 52 `results/50#item52`
- Item 53 `results/50#item53`
- etc.

Any where on my site I'm able to link to a (page 1) accordion item using the following URL;

`example.com/#item2`

However this only works for the records on **page 1**.

When I attempt to link to any record above 50 (page 2, 3, etc.) using this URL, I'm taken to page 1 - nothing happens.

`example.com/#item52`

Presumably this is because I'm missing the pagination segment of the URL `/50`.

For example this works;

- `example.com/50#item52`
- `example.com/150#item154`

The trouble is I don't know what page a record will be on (50/100/150/etc), so creating a direct link is very difficult.

I know that if I wasn't using an accordion this would be much easier but... I am, and can't change at this stage.

Is there any way around this?

Any advice is appreciated.